# SetArgs in nested {}

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphql

I have a long query from which I am parsing it to JSON to get individual values. It all works fine. Unfortunately the problem appears when using SetArgs() in a nested {}. For example, here is my query:

```
{
  System(ID: "1") {
    model {
      type {
        SystemModel{
          CreationModel(isModelCreated: true) {
          name
          }
         }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

And here is my Unity code:

```
public async void GetSystemID () {
        //Importing NestedQuery...
        ...
        query.SetArgs (new { ID= "1", isModelCreated = true }); //How do I provide isModelCreated here

        UnityWebRequest request = await NestedQuery.Post (query);
        JSONNode itemsData = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);
        var parseJSON = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);

    }
```

So in SetArgs, I have to provide a list of arguments, for example ID: "1" and isModelCreated: true. I am able to provide the first argument, but unfortunately the nested query's argument - isModelCreated is not getting recognized as it treats it as:

```
System(ID: "1", isModelCreated: true) {}
```

Do I have to add multiple {} so that it comes in right order or is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: `new {ID="1", new { new { new { new { isModelCreated = true } } } } }` maybe. Totally no expert. 2nd `new` for model, 3rd `new` for type, 4th `new` for SystemModel, 5th `new` for CreationModel. Then pass the args there.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I did try this but I get multiple ```Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.``` errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then let's wait for someone with expertise and we'll both learn something.

Comment: If I understand the docs, it would be `new {ID="1", model = new { type = new { SystemModel = new { CreationModel = new { isModelCreated = true } } } } }`. At least that constructs a valid anonymous object in LinqPad.

Comment: Yes it does construct a valid argument, but when I see my Debug, it displays as ```System(ID: "1", model : { type : { SystemModel : { CreationModel : { isModelCreated : true } } } } })``` which is wrong as I am getting error in the output as well. They are all getting constructed in the first line itself.

Comment: ```"errors":[{"message":"Unknown argument \"model \" on field```